# Time to get passport back from VAC

Tags: visas, canada

I am currently in the US on a B1 visa and applied for a Canadian visit visa. I got a mail from them informing me to submit my passport for final stamping.

If I courier my passport on 25th June in the morning, when can I expect my passport to be back, as I have my tickets to Canada on 20th July? Will that be a problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Oh no they won’t keep your passport for a month go just stamp. It’s 2018. Go ahead. You have plenty of room.

Comment: i was wanting to know when like a tentative date i can get my passport back, as being a foreign national in the US, i am required to carry my passport whenever i travel within the US...and i travel quiet frequently within US

Comment: I thought you just had to carry copies of your i-94 and supporting visa documents.

Answer (score 1):

[**Canada's Visa Application Centre in the US**](https://www.csc-cvac.com/en-us/selfservice/cvac_application_processing_times) suggests that it can take up to three weeks:

> **If you applied online and were asked to submit a passport to the VAC: Please allow for 10-15 business days (this is additional to the visa processing time) for the visa to be issued and your passport returned.**
>
> We recommend that you do not make any travel arrangements until you have received the result of your visa application.